# Typeorm inverse join

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I working with typeorm and I have this two entities

```
@Entity()
class A{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    b_id: number;

    @ManyToOne(() => B, (b) => B.id)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'b_id' })
    b: B;
}

@Entity()
class B{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    title: string;

    @OneToMany(() => A, (a) => a.b_id)
    a: A[];
}


result = db.getRepository(A).createQueryBuilder(A).leftJoinAndSelect('A.b', B);
```

and it translate to:

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B on B.id = A.b_id;
```

how can I revert in ***typeorm*** to get this query

```
SELECT * FROM B LEFT JOIN A on A.b_id = B.id;
```

Thanks